# Changing echoed out text on page to links with Javascript or PHP from MySQL Query

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

So i am making a very basic site where someone types in a box some text and it posts it into mysql.

Example:

Here is my post with a cool link - htt://www.coolness.com

The following script simply grabs the column wanted from the database and echos it on a line.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","####","####");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("####", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['post_content'];
  echo "<br />";
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The link is in plain text and instead I would like either php or javascript to write it as a hyperlink by adding the whole  bit to it.

I've looked through examples, but nothing seemed to work when I tried to apply them.

Any tips would be great.

Comment: This link shows someone solving the same problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027023/regex-php-auto-detect-youtube-image-and-regular-links

Comment: This link shows someone solving the same problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027023/regex-php-auto-detect-youtube-image-and-regular-links

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understood what you meant:

Change to

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo '<a href="' . $row['post_content'] . '">' . $row['post_content'] . '</a>';
  echo "<br />";
  }
```

What this code does, is that it prints the links inside `<a>` tags, which are links.

Comment: Correct, but not everything they post into the database will be a link.

This would just make the whole post in mysql a link.

Here is my post with a cool link - urladdress into Here is my post with a cool link - <a href="urladdress">urladdress</a>

Comment: Okey, now I think I understand what you meant. You could use a regular expression (regex) to find URLs in the text, and then surround those with the <a href=""> stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Use preg_replace() in PHP. Pass it a regular expression for a URL, how you want that matched URL to be replaced, and then the string you pulled from your DB.

You want to turn "http://www.coolness.com" into "http://www.coolness.com'>http://www.coolness.com".

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url) for discussion on regexes for URL matching, and [this piece of the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for more on the preg_replace() function.

EDIT: SO seems to have had fun with my second line there! It should read:

You want to turn "http://www.coolness.com" into "`<a href='http://www.coolness.com'>http://www.coolness.com</a>`".